# My query returns wrong result set, what is wrong for this query?

Tags: sql

Could you tell me please, when I add filter in outer part for below query

[Image of query](https://ibb.co/qr4FKqt)

as where num=1 why it returns;

```
Category_Name Category_Id  Total      Num
hardware1     11           332358,3   1
hardware2     12           365630,7   1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your query and starting data set to your question as text,

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So what is the problem? The query seem to return what you ask.

Comment: Please see the image, according the filter it should returns;                    
hardware1 11 279827 1   and                                                                       hardware2 12 139593,8  1

Comment: I see the image, but I dont know what is the result you want :(. Also not sure where you add the `WHERE`

Comment: I dont understand why it returns wrong result set? I try to understand how it works? Thank you so much..

Comment: We need to see what is the current result and what is the result you expect to try figure out what is wrong

Comment: Why do you refuse to add the sample data and the query as text to your question? Text we can copy and use in our attempt to help you but images are useless.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

That is because you partitioned by Category_name and Category_Id, so the Num is generated separately for each different Category_name and Category_Id.

It's not related with your filter.

Comment: I know how partition is work but problem is here why the filter works for wrong row? I used the filter in outer query I mean for Y table and it returned randomly?